# Can we access GCP bucket via gcp instance using private Network to optimise the Latency?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a query where I need to attach a bucket with GCP VM. I want to know how I can bind the access of bucket only on GCP VM, private network defined on GCP.

The Major context is to write 1TB data at high speed every day.

For the same we are looking for the least latency.

As per us, putting the bucket on public interface will add the latency, which can be optimized by using the private network.

Please let me know how we can implement the same on private network.

Created bucket access it via on GCP VM Instance via Service account which is causing Latency

Answer (score 0):

You are focussing on the wrong item to optimize. Within Google Cloud, network traffic travels on the Google backbone automatically if you have selected/enabled [Premium Tier](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers).

If your VMs do not have public Internet access, then configure [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access). However, that will not increase performance.

There are two primary factors that will affect performance:

1. The distance between your application and the Cloud Storage bucket.
2. The size of the VM, which affects network adapter performance.

Comment: Premium versus Standard Tier networking affects only communications between a VM and the Internet.  Traffic between a VM and a Google service will traverse and stick with the Google "backbone" either way.